# Detach on eloquent collection not working

Tags: laravel

In a Post model I have:

```php
public function tags()
{
  return $this->morphToMany(\App\Models\Tag::class, 'taggable');
}
```

But when I then do:

```php
$posts = Post::all();
$posts->tags()->detach();
```

I get

`Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::inputs does not exist.`

Comment: `$posts = Post::all();` has collection of array. So you have to use `foreach`

Comment: If you're trying to detach all `tags` from all `posts`, you can do a simple `DB::table($nameOfPivot)->delete()` since this is essentially doing the same thing as removing all records from the table. You might have to constrain it with a `where()`, since it's Polymorphic, but it would save having to loop and call X delete queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, it seems like you're trying to remove all the tags from all the existing posts in your application.

If this is what you're trying to do, then follow @A.A Noman comment: you should detach them by iterating the collection, one by one.
Another option is to just clear the intermediate table containing the relations.

If what you're trying to do here is detaching all the tags from a single Post, you can search the post and then detach all the tags:

```php
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->tags()->detach();
```

---

**UPDATE**

To iterate the collection and remove all the Tags from all the Posts:

```php
$posts = Post::all();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->tags()->detach();
}
```

Comment: Indeed the correct answer is to iterate over the posts. I've accepted this answer, maybe for future viewers it would be nice to add a code block showing how it looks like iterating over the posts.

Answer (score -3):

Use Laravel's with()

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

To bring the tags related to this collection

Example:

```
$posts = Post::with('tags');
$posts->tags()->detach();
```

Likewise, if you want to remove a particular entity relationship from the pivot table, you can use the detach method.

For example, if you want to remove a certain author from a book, you can do so.

```
$book->authors()->detach($authorId);
```

Or you can pass multiple IDs as an array.

```
$book->authors()->detach([4, 5, 8]);
```

Or, if you want to remove all authors from a book, use detach without passing any arguments.

```
$book->authors()->detach();
```

Comment: Actually tried that (forgot to mention...), same error

Comment: Likewise, if you want to remove a particular entity relationship from the pivot table, you can use the detach method. 

For example, if you want to remove a certain author from a book, you can do so.

$book->authors()->detach($authorId);
Or you can pass multiple IDs as an array.

$book->authors()->detach([4, 5, 8]);
Or, if you want to remove all authors from a book, use detach without passing any arguments.

$book->authors()->detach();

Comment: `::with('tags')` and `->tags()` are exclusive; `with()` only has an effect when you reference via an attribute, like `->tags`. `->tags()`, as a method with `()`, is a Builder instance and completely ignores usage of `::with('tags')`, so this is not the answer. Also, you're missing a query closure `->first()`, `->get()`, etc. So `$posts->tags()` is actually an error: `'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::tags()'`.